# Getting a date range adjust to days

Tags: javascript, date

I have this date functionality that gets date range of six months, taking into consideration if the range has passed to a new year. How can i alter this date function to take a range of 15 days,while taking into consideration if the range has passed to a new months and/or a new year.

```
var dt = new Date();
var month = new Array();
month[0] = "JAN";
month[1] = "FEB";
month[2] = "MAR";
month[3] = "APR";
month[4] = "MAY";
month[5] = "JUNE";
month[6] = "JULY";
month[7] = "AUG";
month[8] = "SEPT";
month[9] = "OCT";
month[10] = "NOV";
month[11] = "DEC";

var tmonth = dt.getMonth() + 6 <= 11 ? dt.getMonth() + 6 : dt.getMonth() - 6;
var tyear = dt.getMonth() + 6 <= 11 ? dt.getFullYear() : dt.getFullYear() + 1;

var eom = new Date(tyear, tmonth + 1, 0).getDate(); //get last day of the month
var tday = dt.getDate() > eom ? eom : dt.getDate(); //check if the from day of month > last day of month


var frm = dt.getDate() + '-' + month[dt.getMonth()] + '-' + dt.getFullYear().toString().substr(2, 2);
var till = tday + '-' + month[tmonth] + '-' + tyear.toString().substr(2, 2);
```

Comment: Please format your code ;)

Comment: @DmitriPavlutin by format your code what do you mean?

Comment: http://jsbeautifier.org/ :)

Comment: I hope this is just an exercise: never handle date/time conversion yourself, but use a battle-proven library!

Comment: @mb21 yes just an exercise

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution to this would be:

```
var dt = new Date();    
var month = new Array();
month[0] = "JAN";
month[1] = "FEB";
month[2] = "MAR";
month[3] = "APR";
month[4] = "MAY";
month[5] = "JUNE";
month[6] = "JULY";
month[7] = "AUG";
month[8] = "SEPT";
month[9] = "OCT";
month[10] = "NOV";
month[11] = "DEC";

var range = 15;

var tmonth = dt.getMonth() + (range % 12) <= 11 ? dt.getMonth() + (range % 12) : dt.getMonth() - 6;
var tyear = dt.getMonth() + (range % 12) <= 11 ? dt.getFullYear() + Math.floor(range/12) : dt.getFullYear() + Math.floor(range/12) + 1;

var eom = new Date(tyear, tmonth + 1, 0).getDate(); //get last day of the month
var tday = dt.getDate() > eom ? eom : dt.getDate(); //check if the from day of month > last day of month


var frm = dt.getDate() + '-' + month[dt.getMonth()] + '-' + dt.getFullYear().toString().substr(2, 2);
var till = tday + '-' + month[tmonth] + '-' + tyear.toString().substr(2, 2);
```

Now you can choose any range you want - whether it's 6 or 15.